# Remove ending of string with gsub

Tags: regex, r, gsub

I have two possible endings for my string. The first with no numbers:

```
http://www.something.com/test.html
```

the second with numbers (up to two digits)

```
http://www.something.com/test-1.html
http://www.something.com/test-2.html
http://www.something.com/test-3.html
http://www.something.com/test-4.html
http://www.something.com/test-15.html
```

I need to strip the `.html` from the first case and `-1.html` (or whatever number) from the second. The idea is to make the two string comparable to find duplicates.

I think the following should manage the second case

```
gsub("-[0-9]|[1-9][0-9].html", "", string)
```

but is it possible to have a function to manage both cases?

Comment: `gsub("(-[0-9]*)*.html", "", string)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can perhaps use something like this:

```
(-[0-9]+)?\\.html
```

Note that it's safer to escape the dot because an unescaped dot will match any character.

[regex101 demo](http://www.regex101.com/r/fV5sJ3)

Comment: Precisely `gsub("(-[0-9]+)?.html","",string)`. You can't escape the dot with gsub or it will throw an error.

Comment: @CptNemo Did you try escaping the dot with \\ rather than just \?

Comment: Nope. But in any case before the html you can only have "."

Comment: @CptNemo you *can* escape the dot. You should use `\\.` in **R**. This will be safer to ensure your input data is as you expect. Try `gsub( "\\." , " " , "hello.world" )`

Comment: @SimonO101 Thanks for confirming this!

Comment: Message received. :-)